# Maps Api: DirectionRenderer from latlng array

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have an array of latlng objects.

I want to show a DirectionsRenderer along the points in this array.
When you create a DirectionsRenderer, it seems you can only give a DirectionsResult as the direction.

Comment: btw, i'm not using a polyline because i want it to be draggable.

Answer (score 0):

Send the DirectionsService a DirectionsRequest that contains your start point, your end point, and then all your other LatLng objects as waypoints.  (You'll need to put them in a DirectionsWaypoint object.)  That should return a route a DirectionsResult from the DirectionsService that matches your array of LatLng objects if your LatLng objects correspond to a real route along a road or whatever.

If you are hoping to draw arbitrary lines using the DirectionsRenderer rather than a route that Google Maps might come up with, then you probably should probably look at other ways to do it.  You are correct that the DirectionsRenderer needs to receive a DirectionsResult object.  Anything you do to thwart that requirement is likely to just cause headaches sooner or later.

Comment: thx for your answer. i tried waypoints, but i have to many points in the array. I can only have 8 waypoints. The routes i'm making are more than 100km, so they can contain a lot of points.